# jquery ajax result with a wrong format

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem which is the result processed by AJAX, this situation is I would like to pass the result (from AJAX) `'f f f f \'' into get_option('')`, I don't know why it become like this:-

```
<li \'');="" f="" onclick="get_option('f" class="option normal_size">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">f f f f \'</a>
</li>
```

What I want is :-

```
<li onclick="get_option('f f f f\'')" class="option normal_size">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">f f f f \'</a>
</li>
```

I guess the problem might be the space, but I don't know how to solve it, can anyone do me a favour?

my AJAX coding is:-

```
.ajax({                         
    url:'inc_board_saving.php?board_title_input='+board_title_input_encode+'&cate_selected='+cate_selected_input_encode+'&cate_setting_selected='+cate_setting_selected,
    type:'GET',
    data:"nums="+Math.random()*1235,
    success: function(data){
    try{
        var content="";
        var obj =  eval('('+data+')');

        for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            content += "<li class='option normal_size' onclick=get_option('"+obj[i].board_name_encode+"');><a href='javascript:void(0);'>"+obj[i].board_name+"</a></li>";
        }

    }catch(e){
        return;
    }
    }
});
```

**Result:**

```
[
    { "board_id"          : "66",
      "board_name"        : "f f f f '",
      "board_name_encode" : "f f f f \\'"
    },
    { "board_id"          : "65",
      "board_name"        : "t t t t t",
      "board_name_encode" : "t t t t t"
    },
    { "board_id"          : "64",
      "board_name"        : "yy yyy yy",
      "board_name_encode" : "yy yyy yy"
    }
]
```

Comment: try use board_name instead boar_name_encode

Comment: I'd tried already, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
content += '<li class="option normal_size" onclick="get_option(\'' + obj[i].board_name_encode + '\');"><a href="javascript:void(0);">' + obj[i].board_name + '</a></li>';
```